# TensorFlow only works with GPU 0

Tags: python, gpu, gpgpu, tensorflow

I am having a hard time trying to run a tensorflow program in the GPU 1. It doesn't matter if I use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python program.py` or inside the program I use the `tf.device('/gpu:1')`, all the time I get the following error:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:900] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K40c
major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.745
pciBusID 0000:04:00.0
Total memory: 12.00GiB
Free memory: 11.90GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:717] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 1.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 2.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 4.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 8.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 16.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 32.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 64.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 128.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 256.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 512.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 1.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 2.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 4.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 8.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 16.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 32.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 64.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 128.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 256.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 512.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 1.00GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 2.00GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 4.00GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 8.00GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 16.00GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:73] Allocating 11.31GiB bytes.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:83] GPU 0 memory begins at 0x9047a0000 extends to 0xbd8325334
F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:383] Check failed: CUDA_SUCCESS == dynload::cuCtxSetCurrent(context) (0 vs. 216)
F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:383] Check failed: CUDA_SUCCESS == dynload::cuCtxSetCurrent(context) (0 vs. 216)
F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:383] Check failed: CUDA_SUCCESS == dynload::cuCtxSetCurrent(context) (0 vs. 216)
Aborted
```

This doesn't happen when running with GPU0, but the problem is that someone else is using that GPU and GPU1 is idle

Comment: I would guess that there is some hardcoded reference to device 0 in the tensor flow code base somewhere.

Comment: @talonmies I use different GPUs all the time with tensorflow (using CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to select GPUs), so I'm pretty sure that this way is working in general

Comment: @etarion: Working *in general* and working for this particular case are two different things: Clearly the internal context handling routines are blowing up - error 216 is "CUDA_ERROR_CONTEXT_ALREADY_IN_USE "

Answer (score 3):

If you are using CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 make sure that "someone else" is running with CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0.

By default, if no CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is specified, a tensorflow process hogs all the GPUs even if it is not actively using them. They may appear idle, but will not accessible to subsequent tensorflow processes. However, you can use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES on each process to allocate different GPUs to each.

Remember that within each process, the tensorflow devices /gpu:0, /gpu:1, etc. are relative to the process, not global for your machine...so, they will refer to whatever cuda visible devices are available to that process...put another way, if you want each process to use 1 GPU you would refer to /gpu:0 in the the code for all of them while using CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to assign specific GPUs to each process.

Use command `nvidia-smi` to see which processes are using which GPUs.